# Django - Show shell output command while process is running

Tags: python, django, shell

I'm building a django-based web application that needs to run a shell command. For example: I need to show a live output of ping command. With some structures below:

Django view:

```
<div class="output-panel">
     <span class="live-output">OUTPUT HERE</span>
</div>
<button onclick="runCommand()">Run Command</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function runCommand() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/runCommand',
        success: function(data) {
             $(".live-output").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Django function (/api/runCommand url goes to api.runCommand):

```
import subprocess
def runCommand(request):
    cmd = "ping google.com"
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
    nextline = process.stdout.readline()

    if nextline == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(nextline)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Is there any way to send the sys.stdout back to my view everytime it generates a new output line ? (Not when the process DONE, but ALONGSIDE with the running process).

Comment: Websockets, server-sent events or long-polling with ajax. I usually stick with websockets and [`django-channels`](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that matter.